# Program that reads three lines of text and counts each alphabet letter (C)

Tags: c, string

I'm fairly new to coding and am currently enrolled in a course at school teaching C. We have been given an assignment that requires as follows:

Write a program that inputs three lines of text and uses the function `strchr` to determine the number of occurrences of each letter of the alphabet (uppercase and lowercase should be counted as the same). Store the totals for each letter in an array and print the result.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    int alphabet[26] = { 0 };
    char string[3][SIZE];
    int i, j;
    int c;

    printf("Enter three lines of text:\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        fgets(string[i], SIZE, stdin);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; &string[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            string[i][j] = tolower(string[i][j]);
        }
        for (j = 0; &string[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (strchr(&string[i][j], ('a' + j)) != NULL) {
                alphabet[j]++;
            }
        }       
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c: %d\n", ('a' + i), alphabet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the current program I have is that the counter for the array `alphabet[]` doesn't seem to be incrementing the count properly.

The output should count, for example, increment by 1 for each occurrence of every letter, but the results are all 0.

Any other tips or words of advice are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you do any debugging? The right way to tackle this is to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: `for (j=0; &string[i][j]` --> `for (j=0; string[i][j]`. Your compiler should have warned you about these lines. Please heed the warnings.

Comment: @kaylum I have tried with `-Wextra -Wall -Werror ` but gcc didn't say anything, the test is weird but valid. Have you an idea of flag to catch it ?

Comment: Hello guys! I've actually just heard from a fellow classmate that it's important to learn how to use a debugger when first learning how to code. I'll take your advice to heart @kaylum and look into the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test for end of line is wrong, 
no need to loop several time just parse the string and count the letters
You want letter between `'a'`and `'z'`, check if the char is in the range and count it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    int alphabet[26] = { 0 };
    char string[3][SIZE];
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter three lines of text:\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        fgets(string[i], SIZE, stdin);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; string[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            char c = tolower(string[i][j]);
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                alphabet[c - 'a']++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c: %d\n", ('a' + i), alphabet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This program works great. I have a question though: What does it mean if you write alphabet[c - 'a']? Since alphabet[] is an integer array, does it mean that the index would subtract the integer value of 'a' from c? Sorry, I tried to text it out on my own but am having trouble... :(

Comment: a `char` is an `int` (unsigned), by chance the characters a to z are contiguous into ascii code. Your array as 26 slot from 0 for a to 25 for z. To convert char value to slot you just have to do `- 'a'` Like you do when you do `'a' + i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change loop terminating condition from  &string[i][j] != '\0'; to string[i][j] != '\0';
strchr will return the address from the string where match was found, so you should save the non null address to pass it to next call to strchr
Something like this:

```
tmpPtr = &string[i][j];
while ((tmpPtr=strchr(tmpPtr, string[i][j])) != NULL) {
alphabet[string[i][j] - 'a']++;
}
```